# Changing mainactivity inner layout background from preference activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have a preferences activity. From this activity I want to be able to change the background color of one of the layouts in the main activity.

Right now when I try to run the settings activity with the "if" loops that carry the change in background color, the app crashes.

The click listener that opens the settings activity:

```html
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentPreferences = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentPreferences);

                //startActivityForResult(intentPreferences);
            }
        });
```

The preferencescreen layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:id="@+id/prefSwitch"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="You want a yellow or white background?"
        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

My preferences activity:

```html
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private static final boolean ALWAYS_SIMPLE_PREFS = false;
    private SwitchPreference settingsSwitch;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        PreferenceManager mPreferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newdeliverylayout);
        if (mPreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences().getBoolean("pref_sync", true)){
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else{
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

The preferences screen opens normally if I comment out the rl.setBackgroundColor lines in the if loop

Comment: It's crashing because you're trying to access and modify a layout that's in another activity. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it so each time the main activity loads it checks shared preferences and loads the color to what ever is in the preferences. If the preferences is null then just set it to a default color?

So for example on you can set the color like this. (ive just put a hex color reference but you can change it to whatever you wish.

```
public void setBackgroundColor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("color", "#FFFFFF");
    editor.commit()
}
```

Then in the main activity just make sure you call this method every time it loads / reloads

```
public void getBackgroundColor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.contains("color")) {
        String myColor = sharedPreferences.getString("color", null);
        mybackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myColor));
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. To call that method every time my main activity loads, do I put a call to that method in my onCreate method?

Comment: Yeah, you can also put it in onResume if you need to.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement this solution tomorrow and if it works I will accept your answer+upvote ofcourse

Comment: Awesome, if you have any issues just let me know!